# "The ConnectionString property is invalid." when I know it is valid

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I have an ASP.NET MVC application where the database is on an IBM i-Series server. I have the application development close to completion when I started to get a `The ConnectionString property is invalid.` error popping up:

1. only at log on
2. after the first successful log on after rebuilding
3. anyone logged on can still work normally

Also, note that this problem only shows up for one project in my solution. The other project uses the exact same connection string and doesn't have this problem (copied and pasted to be 100% sure). I am in active development on these projects, but have not touched the connections strings nor worked with the `AccountController` and related model classes after getting the login working.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and .NET version 3.5.

Connection String:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IbmIConnectionString" connectionString="DataSource=192.168.50.200;DefaultCollection=QMFILES;Naming=sql;UserID=XXX;Password=XXXX;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Account Controller Logon method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        string fullName = String.Empty;
        string employeeId = String.Empty;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                EmployeeLoginModel elm = new EmployeeLoginModel();
                elm.GetUserInfo(model.UserName, model.Password, out fullName, out employeeId);
                // Update the AuthCookie to include the last 4 digits of the SSN.
                string userDataString = String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", model.Password, fullName.Trim(), employeeId.Trim());
                HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
                FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration, ticket.IsPersistent, userDataString);
                authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
                Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Employee Login Model:

```
public class EmployeeLoginModel
{
    public string UserName { set; get; }
    public string Password { set; get; }

    private iDB2Connection conn;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EmployeeLoginModel"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public EmployeeLoginModel()
    {
        conn = new iDB2Connection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IbmIConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether [is valid user] [the specified username].
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username">The username.</param>
    /// <param name="password">The password.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     <c>true</c> if [is valid user] [the specified username]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    public bool IsValidUser(string username, string password)
    {
        int count = 0;

        // Get the data from the iSeries
        using (conn)
        {
            string sqlStatement = "SELECT COUNT(XXXXX) FROM XXXXX WHERE UPPER(XXXXXX) = @1 AND XXXXXX = @2";

            iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command(sqlStatement, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@1", username.ToUpper());
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@2", password);
            conn.Open();
            count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            conn.Close();
        }

        return ((count == 0) ? false : true);
    }
```

Comment: More details?  Maybe the connection string, how you retrieve the connection string, what your account controller looks like?  Post your SVN logs too, I never believe "I didn't touch it" anymore.  ;)

Comment: BTW are you sure you want your password listed here?? If that's your real password I suggest changing it immediately... (Just editing your post here won't help because people can see the history of the edits.)

Comment: I don't have SVN logs as it isn't on version control yet.

Comment: Crap! Server is internal only luckily.

Comment: The SystemINet URL doesn't work.

Comment: I've flagged for moderator attention so that they can remove the revisions that have the password in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting this, I had a theory. I was switching between browsers getting things setup for a demo. I changed my method to:

```
    public bool IsValidUser(string username, string password)
    {
        int count = 0;

        // Get the data from the iSeries
        using (iDB2Connection conn = new iDB2Connection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IbmIConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string sqlStatement = "SELECT COUNT(XXXXXX) FROM XXXXXX WHERE UPPER(XXXXXX) = @1 AND XXXXXX = @2";

            iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command(sqlStatement, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@1", username.ToUpper());
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@2", password);
            conn.Open();
            count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            conn.Close();
        }

        return ((count == 0) ? false : true);
    }
```

It seems to be working now. I wonder if that was the problem.

Comment: @jfar, what's wrong with inline SQL? It looks proper to me, it even uses parameters to avoid SQL injection, so this is a perfectly valid code.

Comment: @Darin: Parameters: good. Inline Sql: bad.  The problem is in discoverability of problems in the event of a data model change.  Let's say they rename one of the field names, which is generally more common than people think.  The only way to find out this is a problem is if the particular method that selects on that field name is called.  Meaning, it's a runtime error.

Comment: @Chris and what do you suggest to do and please don't tell me to use an ORM as renaming a column would break this ORM at runtime the same way it would break this code.

Comment: @Darin: If they were using stored procedures, a quick recompile of the procedure will tell you exactly which ones will fail on a field change.  At that point it's much easier to either change the proc to rename the field on output OR locate in the code where those procs are used.  Or, if using some type of ORM/Code gen, a new code gen would lead to compile time errors that quickly pointed out problem areas.

Comment: @Darin: The issue is whether it's a runtime or compile time problem.  With code gen and procs, it's compile time.  Inline is runtime.

Comment: Your `using` in the original question would dispose of the `conn` object and then you'd try to use it again.  The way you're using it in this code is correct.

Comment: @Chris, I really don't understand how using stored procedure will prevent you from runtime errors when renaming for example some columns in the database and forgetting to sync the code.

Comment: @Darin: Let's say I have "select field1, field2 from mytable" in a proc.  Then I rename field1 to be fieldX in mytable.  I then recompile my procs.  During the recompile the server will complain that "field1 is not a member of mytable" or something to that effect (compile time validation).  I can then make a choice either change the proc to say "select fieldX as field1, field2 from mytable" OR I change the proc and then do a search for all usages of the proc in the code base.  Perfect? not even close.  Better than inline sql? absolutely.

Comment: My issue with inline sql is that this code is impossible to test outside of integration or manual testing.  There is also the concern that this code is used as something else.  Why wouldn't it be static?  Why does it have properties?  Why isn't it abstracted behind a DAL?  Sometimes inline SQL is fine, this is too close to the surface ( UI ).  There is also the magic string issue.  --- I agree with Darin on the schema change issue.  Nothing helps that well when you change a db column from the database and need to migrate up.  I use NHib or EF to do code changes and push the schema down.

Comment: @Darin: Also, I can have a DBA do performance tweaks on a proc all day long without redeploying the site.  With inline sql, I need a DBA and a developer and I have to redeploy the whole thing.

Comment: @Chris Lively but that doesn't help any db->code mapping get updated and now you have to adjust to this change in two places. I think Darin is right here.  You're always SOL when db tables change.

Comment: So your saying I need to create a new stored proc for every sql statement I run? I thought that was the purpose of the model layer so it can separate out the database from the code? That is another layer then.

Comment: Also note: We have three developers total. No DBA, unless you count me as the DBA for the projects I work on. Making a field name change is a feat we don't take casually as we may have many, many RPG programs that also use the field(s). We may make fields bigger or add to the table, but those won't typically cause a problem with SQL code.

Comment: I am willing to listen. I am still quite new at ASP.NET development.

Answer (score 5):

Another very trivial reason for getting this error is, that the required DB2 drivers are not installed.

The inner exception stated

> Unable to load DLL 'cwbdc.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>   Type: System.DllNotFoundException

Comment: Potential related question to this answer if you try to connect to a DB2 on an iSeries/AS400: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56007414/error-whie-connecting-as400-unable-to-load-dll-cwbdc-dll

Answer (score 1):

I think because you use the connection outside the using statement, so it will be closed after go to other function, so when you call in IsValidUser, it will throw exception. in the second code, you use it in using statement, after call it will be Garbage Collection released. And it is work.